# Webpage dropdown menu filtering

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, filtering

I'm creating a web page where the dropdown menu will have about 60 options (alphabetically ordered) to choose from. I'm trying to look up the method used to quickly filter through them by pressing 'e' (for example) on the keyboard, and then the selection will automatically move down to the options starting with 'e'.
I'm searching google without any luck yet. If somebody could just point me to the correct search wording i should use, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for autocomplete: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

I've used this one before and it's fairly easy to implement.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the even more watered down version (no search bar). I just want the user to type a letter.... and then that to filter down the list to where that letter is located

Comment: ...actually... was able to use the above and make it work for my purpose. Thanks for the info Greyson R.